# What is the purpose of the '@' symbol in CSS?

Tags: css, syntax, symbols

I just stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451541/css-font-face-anti-aliasing) and I noticed the user is using some notation I've never seen before:

```css
@font-face {
   /* CSS HERE */
}
```

So is this `@` symbol something new in CSS3, or something old that I've somehow overlooked? Is this something like where with an ID you use `#`, and with a class you use `.`? Google didn't give me any good articles related to this. What is the purpose of the  `@` symbol in CSS?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`@` has been around since the days of `@import` in CSS1, although it's arguably becoming increasingly common in the recent `@media` (CSS2, CSS3) and `@font-face` (CSS3) constructs. The `@` syntax itself, though, as I mentioned, is not new.

These are all known in CSS as **at-rules**. They're special instructions for the browser, not directly related to styling of (X)HTML/XML elements in Web documents using rules and properties, although they do play important roles in controlling how styles are applied.

Some code examples:

```css
/* Import another stylesheet from within a stylesheet */
@import url(style2.css);

/* Apply this style only for printing */
@media print {
    body {
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
    }
}

/* Embed a custom web font */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans';
    src: local('DejaVu Sans Regular'), url(/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf);
}
```

- [`@font-face` rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) define custom fonts for use in your designs that aren't always available on all computers, so a browser downloads a font from the server and sets text in that custom font as if the user's computer had the font.
- [`@media` rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-media), in conjunction with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries) (formerly only [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html)), control which styles are applied and which aren't based on what media the page is being displayed in. In my code example, only when printing a document should all text be set in black against a white (the paper) background. You can use media queries to filter out print media, mobile devices and so on, and style pages differently for those.

At-rules have no relation to [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors) whatsoever. Because of their varying nature, different at-rules are defined in different ways across numerous different modules. More examples include:

- [Conditional rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional)
- [Keyframe animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations)
- [Paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page)

*(this list is far from exhaustive)*

You can find another non-exhaustive list at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/At-rule).

Comment: @media print{
/* Are you trying to print a video or audio file?? */
}

Answer (score 29):

`@` is used to define a rule.

[@import](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#at-import)
@page
[@media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#at-media-rule)
@font-face
@charset
[@namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#defining)

**The above are called [`at-rule`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#at-rules)s.**

Comment: What do you mean by "define a rule"?

Comment: At-rules encapsulate a bunch of CSS rules and apply them to something specific. (http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/atrules/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The accepted answer above talks about `at-rules`, but never actually stops to answer the question of what `@` does.

Answer (score 7):

An example of @media that might be useful to illustrate it further:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px)
{
    span.sizedImage
    {
        height:135px;
        width: 174px;
    }
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 1441px)
{
    span.sizedImage
    {
        height:150px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

This will vary the size of the image conditionally on the size of the screen, using a smaller image on a smaller screen.  The first block would address screens up to width 1440px; the second would address screens larger than 1440px.

This comes in handy with things like tabs that float drop or scroll on smaller screens; you can often drop the font size of the tab labels down a point size on smaller screens and have them all fit.

Answer (score 3):

The ProBoards CSS style also uses these as variables.

Here's a small snipptt from one of their CSS pages:

```
@wrapper_width: 980px;
@link_color: #c06806;
@link_font: 100% @default_forum_text_font_family;
@link_decoration: none;

#wrapper { width: @wrapper_width; margin: 0 auto; overflow-x: hidden; }
table { table-layout: fixed; }
a { cursor: pointer; color: @link_color; font: @link_font; text-decoration: @link_decoration; }
```

NOTE: not native, see first comment.

Comment: RE: your "NOTE:" -- there is no first comment; it must have been deleted.  Care to include the details in your questions (as you should always do with important details)?

Answer (score 1):

@ is used as a rule specification. Like `@font-face`