# What does the "@" in this CSS statement mean?

Tags: css, webkit

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

What does the "@" and "100%" mean?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css

Comment: This is not a direct duplicate of that question, as it refers to -webkit specific rules that are not documented there.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a duplicate (at least, not of the question linked to). The linked question refers to very different `@` rules.

Comment: So this is why I got an upvote on my answer to that question out of the blue. While my answer does explain the purpose of the `@` symbol, I agree with Duncan and James in that it doesn't adequately answer this specific WebKit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are CSS3 rules that have been defined by the webkit development team, in advance of formal acceptance as part of the CSS3 specification—hence the inclusion of -webkit in the selector. The @ indicates that this is a CSS rule, rather than a standard selector. @-webkit-keyframes is for specifying keyframes for CSS visual effect animation properties.

You can define as many keyframes as you like for the animation; in the case you have given only the final keyframe (when 100% of the animation is complete) has been defined. [The full syntax and documentation for these rules can be found here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW4)

For instance, if you wanted the animation to start slowly and then accelerate, while starting and ending smoothly, you could set intermediate keyframes that had non-linear steps in the degree of rotation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(168deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "@" declares an At-Rule in the stylesheet. It most certainly has a special meaning, in every case.

The "100%" refers to the final state of the CSS Animation defined by the @keyframes rule, or in this case the @-webkit-keyframes rule. You actually have to declare the first (0%) and final (100%) states of the animation so the user agent knows when to start and stop the animation.

Here's some more:
At-Rules are directives to the rendering engine; they extend the CSS Rule Set syntax beyond regular Selector and Declaration blocks. 
At-Rules are declared with an At-Keyword, which is simply "@keyword", followed by an At-Rules Statement relative to the At-Keyword used. Example: @charset "ISO-8859-15";

Optional arguments can follow the At-Keyword depending on the At-Rule Statement type. Example: @media screen{ color:#000; }, where screen is the optional argument.