# What is meant by @ in css?

Tags: css, at-command, sign

I`m trying to manipulate the css of the zimbra, I do not mean a thing, in some style files i found this:

```
body    {   @ChromeBg@  }
```

who can explain the usage of @, after and before `ChromeBg`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css

Comment: @Sreejesh: This question is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to Zimbra, apparently. I hope this explains more:

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Creating_Themes_Long_Version#Editing_Theme_Substitution_Files

Comment: Well, where i can find the main css of zimbra, i just want to make webclient right to let.

Comment: The main css? You mean the substitition file? I don't really know. But apparently, you can just add your styles to the `body` rule you have above: `{@ChromeBg@; your style here }`

Answer (score 2):

The use of @ differs based on the place it is present...

When @ is present only at front, it is called At-rule.... eg: @import - means it allows u to import one style sheet into another...

When @ is used in both sides of a word, it is a substitution file... eg: @somedata@  - indicates an entry in the substitution file(s) with that name should be placed at that spot in the CSS files..

Hope its useful for u...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is their way to specify variables in CSS. I can see

```
ChromeBg = background-color:@_BaseColor_@;
```

at http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Creating_Themes_Long_Version

Answer (score 1):

see these two links i am also learning about use of @ in css.

I hope this will help you also :-

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i dont know what is this but i got reference link , i am sharing this

http://files.zimbra.com/docs/skins/Themes.html#skinvariables

but we use this like css

it is importing another css file in here

```
eg - @import url("reset.css");
```

it is calling font face method

```
eg- @font-face {}
```