# Purpose of @keyframes in css3

Tags: css, css-animations

I came across `@keyframes` somewhere in css3 codes. I couldn't find about it in much detail in stackoverflow. Even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css) answers the @ rules except @keyframes.

Can somebody explain or provide a good link about @keyframes in detail?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/

They just set the parameters for different stages of an animation, this lets you perform complex animations using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The `@keyframes` at-rule is intended to define a CSS3 animation and usually has vendor prefixes in the real CSS code, since the standardization/implementation dust hasn't settled down yet. You can find more about WebKit's implementation (`@-webkit-keyframes`) from [their blog post](http://www.webkit.org/blog/324/css-animation-2/)... or about the general stuff [here](http://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&q=css3+keyframes).