# what is the symbol @ in a ccs value?

Tags: css

I saw @name (for example) @menu in css value. I noticed it is related to a php array but I dont know what is it exactly. Is it used for refer to the data structure in php code? Does @ means special thing or just a part of the value like a normal letter.

For example:

```
.menu .block {
  background-color: @menucolor;
  border-color: @menuborders;
}
```

When I search @ in css, I saw @rules in css. But I cannot find information about @ in css value. Anyone knows? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the '@' symbol in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

This is properety in CSS preprocessor like a LESS or SCSS. Not `at-rules` becaus only @import @page @media @font-face @charset @namespace are at-rules.