# Passing value from a mixin to a class, using escaped characters

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a map generator that add a post particle:

```
@mixin generator {
  @each $key, $value in $config {
        $infix: '\@#{$key}' !global;
        @content
      }
    }
```

I used the mixin above in multiple situations to add the particle at the end, like:

```
.y- {
  @include generator {
    &-n#{$infix} {
      display: none !important;
    }
    &-in#{$infix} {
      display: inline !important;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid CSS after "&-none": expected selector, was "@"\n

What I want to have is:

```
.y-n@key_name1{
    display: none !important;
}

.y-n@key_name2{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

This appears only when I us `\@`.

I can add it this particle when I create the class, but like I said I want to use it in multiple situations and to variate the particle base on conditions, so I need to be in mixin.

Comment: I can help but you're calling `@include utility_generator` but your `@mixin` is called `generator`? Are you purposely running a loop? Are these typos.

Comment: thanks, edited, just a copy paste mistake, the name should be the same. yes I'm intentionally running a loop; there are multiple 'strings' that I want to add at the end of a class name

Comment: I'm with ya you want to run through an array and output the key in the class, gimme a few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works...

```
$config: (
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c'
);

@mixin generator {
  @each $key, $value in $config {
        $infix: '-#{$key}' !global;
        @content
      }
    }

.y- {
  @include generator {
    &-n#{$infix} {
      display: none !important;
    }
    &-in#{$infix} {
      display: inline !important;
    }
  }
}
```

See this sassmeister https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/324c3c0003a91eb676b00dfe1877cae0

But as soon as you add..

```
\@
```

..to your `$infix` variable key string, it throws an error!

```
$infix: '\@#{$key}' !global;
```

I assume it is `\@` that breaks your sass/css.

If you see [What is the purpose of the '@' symbol in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css) question you can only use `@` symbol for (examples)...

```
/* Import another stylesheet from within a stylesheet */
@import url(style2.css);

/* Apply this style only for printing */
@media print {
    body {
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
    }
}

/* Embed a custom web font */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans';
    src: local('DejaVu Sans Regular'), url(/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf);
}
```

Maybe ditch the `\@` and your sass will run ok?

Comment: it is not working, the issue is with the special character. If I change in your code: $infix: '\@'; , will trow an error like in my code; I need something to tell sass, do not interpret/parse take it as a string

Comment: See updated answer though its answering it in a good. I'm just sure @content can pass variables through. Logically you think it would allow it.

Comment: just fixed all my typos sorry

Comment: yes, the issue was not with my mixin, but with the @ symbol. The solution I found was to use \\@; I'm testing the use of the @ to define a media query class, like col-7@sm