# How do I make my font smooth on my website, as text-shadow and font-smooth are not working?

Tags: css, fonts

I have done headers on http://downpublic.info/wpdemo/forSky/up-next/. However, the text looks jaggered and not smooth.

I have tried the following:

```
font-smooth: always;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #color;
```

Now the top one doesn't seem to work (I heard it doesn't work in certain instances), and the text-shadow seems to make the font glow, more than smooth.

Where should I be looking in the CSS for issues causing this, as I'm stumped?

Comment: You could look into [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)

Comment: Hi Asad, surely it should just work with a ttf? It shouldnt make it jaggered surely? thanks for the comment

Comment: I think you'll find an answer to you question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451541/css-font-face-anti-aliasing

Comment: Hi David,text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); i take it that this maybe better, would i have to replace the rgba with the hex color?  Thanks for this.

Comment: There is no `font-smooth` property in any specification or current draft. There is just `-webkit-font-smoothing`, implemented on WebKit browsers in Mac platform (and it has its own set of values, which does not include `always`).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela There was, at least up till css3: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop

Comment: @Asad, it *was* in 2002 draft, removed when the draft was updated in 2009, probably largely due to lack of implementation efforts.

Comment: @KirstyHarris, the page is rather complicated and seems to result in different styles being sent to different browsers. You have not specified which browser(s) display it wrong and in which sense, but at least Chrome seems to use `candalregular, Geneva, sans-serif` for the `h2`, differently from Firefox, which uses Verdana. It should probably be debugged locally by someone who knows well the tools used.

Comment: Hi jukka unfortunately this is something I have not personally built, and understandably I know where u are coming from, my friend has asked me to sort this. Would this be easier for me to recode the menu font a fresh?

Comment: I don't know why it would. I know he has referenced the menu to .text h1 etc, where I know he has used separate for normal h1 would it be best I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should avoid using ttf or otf fonts in a web production, because they will look jagged in some browsers when scaled. You should use embeddable opentype formats instead.

You can use [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate a font package that contains web-safe versions of your font (also includes css), that you can use with your webpage.

Comment: This is the first time I hear that there's a difference in font smoothing based on the format. Do you have some sources for that?

Comment: @Pekka Sure, [1](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/), [2](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/05/28/quick-tip-always-generate-web-safe-fonts-when-using-font-face/)

Comment: The information is interesting, but the page uses fonts of the Verdana and Arial families, and I don’t think you can legally use them as downloadable fonts (web fonts). There are some interesting free fonts that could be used instead.

Comment: Jukka theses are on dreamweaver which it has been built on

Comment: Hi all,Please help, ive tried everything and the font still looks grainy. Can someone please have a look at the code (as ive outsourced this) and tell me what to do, is it the background thats the issue?

Comment: @KirstyHarris Have you tried setting Cleartype off on the box you're testing this on?

Comment: Asad I'm not sure how to do that can u tell me where I need t insert?

Comment: Hi asad is there a CSS fix thou, it's just I'm sure we cannot expect every person t do this on their browsers